# SQL Server - Order by combination of number and letter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I would like to sort on a VARCHAR combination of one number and one letter. 
First sort on the number low - high, then letter A - Z.

Sample data sorted:

```
1a
2b
2d
4e
6a
```

It seems like this should be achievable with PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', value))?

Comment: Simply `order by col`

Comment: How is `order by col` not the solution to your question, as suggested by @jarlh? You might want to extend your sample data with more values so your question is more explicit.

Comment: @jarlh Wow, you are right.. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a basic order by:

```
order by col
```

Comment: This will fail if the column has 222a & 2c

Comment: @Srinika, always one digit followed by one character according to OP.